# Single.retry(3) called only once

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have three api calls, the requirements are

1. Second api and third api should be called only when the first one is successful.
2. When the first api throws exception, retry that call
3. When the first api fails for 3 times, stop retrying and pass the Exception to the subscriber
4. When the first is successful but the second api fails, resume with default value for second api

Using the code that looks like below, the first api isn't retried at all

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Single.zip(
            getA().retry(3),
            getB().onErrorResumeNext(Single.just("defaultB")),
            getC(),
            (a, b, c) -> a)
            .subscribe(a -> {
                System.out.println(a);
            }, error -> {
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
            });

}

private static Single<String> getA() {
    System.out.println("getA()");
    return Single.error(new Exception("a"));
}

private static Single<String> getB() {
    System.out.println("getB()");
    return Single.error(new Exception("b"));
}

private static Single<String> getC() {
    System.out.println("getB()");
    return Single.error(new Exception("b"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the `Single` is retried but the call to `getA()` doesn't as it is not part of an RxJava chain. You call it once and thus the printout happens only once.

To see it retried in its entirety, wrap the contents of the method into `defer`:

```java
private static Single<String> getA() {
    return Single.defer(() -> {
        System.out.println("getA()");
        return Single.error(new Exception("a"));
    });
}
```

Also if your requirements say A and then B+C together, so the following sequence is more appropriate:

```java
getA().retry(3)
.flatMap(a -> Single.zip(
    getB().onErrorResumeNext(Single.just("defaultB")), 
    getC(),
    (b, c) -> a
))
.subscribe(a -> {
            System.out.println(a);
        }, error -> {
            System.out.println(error.getMessage());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The zip is not correct if your calls are dependent, How about like this:

```
Single.just("input")
  .flatMap(a -> getA()).retry(3)
  .flatMap(a -> getB()).onErrorResumeNext(Single.just("defaultB"))
  .flatMap(b -> getC())
  .subscribe(a -> {
    System.out.println(a);
  }, error -> {
    System.err.println(error.getMessage());
  });
```